Terraform - Optional map(objects)
I want to use the optional parameter to pass optional parameters:
variable "clients" {
  type = map(object({
    description         = string
    initiated_login_uri = optional(string)
    allowed_clients     = optional(list(string), [])
  }))
}

resource "auth0_client" "this" {
  for_each           = var.clients
  description        = each.value.description
  initiate_login_uri = each.value.initiated_login_uri
  allowed_clients    = each.value.allowed_clients
}

For which, as I understood I should be able to send
clients = {
  client_0 = {
    description         = "Description"
    initiated_login_uri = "http://example.com"
    allowed_clients     = ["XXXXXX"]
  },
  
  client_1 = {
    description = "Description"
  }
}

But got

all map elements must have the same type

Any way to fix that? Meaning each element of a map with non-mandatory attributes?

The way you declared and set the variable clients is valid Terraform code.
Consider the following code:
variable "clients" {
  type = map(object({
    description        = string
    initiate_login_uri = optional(string)
    allowed_clients    = optional(list(string), [])
  }))
  default = {
    client_0 = {
      description        = "Description"
      initiate_login_uri = "http://example.com"
      allowed_clients    = ["XXXXXX"]
    },
    client_1 = {
      description = "Description"
    }
  }
}

output "clients" {
  value       = var.clients
  description = "Value of clients"
}

Running terraform plan using Terraform v1.9.4:
Changes to Outputs:
  + clients = {
      + client_0 = {
          + allowed_clients    = [
              + "XXXXXX",
            ]
          + description        = "Description"
          + initiate_login_uri = "http://example.com"
        }
      + client_1 = {
          + allowed_clients    = []
          + description        = "Description"
          + initiate_login_uri = null
        }
    }

The problem is that you need to ensure that the default values for initiate_login_uri and allowed_clients are valid when setting the correspondent properties of auth0_client.
For example, var.clients.initiated_login_uri default value is null but the value of auth0_client.initiate_login_uri must be an HTTPS URL or an empty string, according to auth0_client documentation.
So, instead of:
variable "clients" {
  type = map(object({
    description         = string
    initiated_login_uri = optional(string)
    allowed_clients     = optional(list(string), [])
  }))
}

Try:
variable "clients" {
  type = map(object({
    description         = string
    initiated_login_uri = optional(string, "") // <-------- changed default value
    allowed_clients     = optional(list(string), [])
  }))
}

You might need to change the default value of allowed_clients as well. If an empty array ([]) is not valid, try changing the default value to null.

Good catch. However, I don't think this is the core-issue here (now got all map elements must have the same type.). It seems that clients must contains both initiated_login_uri and allowed_clients to be passed. It seems I cannot mark them as optional.

@Mornor which version of Terraform are you using? Is it an old version? I did test your code (without using the auth0_resource) and there were no errors regarding clients variable.  I'm using Terraform v1.9.4.

v1.7.5. Let me actually check if that's the issue! So with your code, you can pass both the clients I defined (client_0 and client_1)? There's some weird stuff going on...

@Mornor v1.7.5 supports optional attributes. Try setting the default value of initiate_login_uri to empty string, and remove the var.clients.allowed_clients for the time being, just to see if it works.

Still got the all map elements must have the same type.. I'll accept you answer though, because your TF plan output is what I'm looking for. Which makes me think the error is coming from somewhere else.

@Mornor try commenting out var.clients.allowed_clients for the time being, as I mentioned. Also, comment the auth0_client resource and run the plan to see what happens.

I'm so stupid. I was not updating the variables definition block of the child ... Now everything work as expected. Thanks a lot!
